# How to split wchar_t array and assign details to variables in C?

Tags: c, arrays, wchar-t

```
wchar_t str[]=L"The results are:\nfilename=test.xml\nusername=Tom/";
wchar_t filename[32];
wchar_t username[32];
```

I have a `wchar_t` array contained in `str` variable.

I want to split `str` variable and assign details with variables:

```
filename="test.xml";
username="Tom";
```

How can I split `str` variable and put details into the related variables in C? Especially trailing `/` should be included in `username` variable.

Comment: The [`wcstok_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcstok) function might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

If the filename/username are always on the same lines, this should work:

```
short i;
i = 0;
while (str[i])
{
  if (str[i] == '\n')
  {
    line++; 
  }

  if (line == 1 && str[i] == '=')
  {  i++;
     while (stri[i] && stri[i+1] != '\n')
     {   
         filename[fnlen++] = stri[i];
         i++;  
     }
     filename[fnlen] = 0;
  }
  if (line == 2 && str[i] == '=')
  {  i++;
     while (stri[i] && stri[i+1] != '\n')
     {
         username[fnlen++] = stri[i];
         i++;
     }
     username[fnlen] = 0;
     break;
  }
  i++;
}
```